# Searching for multiple text strings in Oracle procedures

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a single search for multiple text strings within a stored procedure. The following code works for test1, but when I try both test1 & test2 I get no results; no error either.

The line for test2 is remarked-out now.

```
SELECT name, line, text 
FROM   user_source
WHERE  type = 'PROCEDURE' 
AND    UPPER(text) LIKE UPPER('%test1%')
-- AND TEXT LIKE UPPER('%test2%') 
ORDER BY NAME;
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: I guess you mean **OR**

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR` because if you use an `AND` you will only come out postive if you find both strings. Maybe you miss the upper(text) also

```
SELECT name, line, text 
FROM   user_source
WHERE  type = 'PROCEDURE' 
AND UPPER(text) LIKE UPPER('%test1%')
OR  upper(TEXT) LIKE UPPER('%test2%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there isn't a line with both "text1" and "text2" strings. You would have to use an OR in that case.

```
SELECT NAME, LINE, TEXT 
FROM   USER_SOURCE
WHERE  TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' 
AND (UPPER(TEXT) LIKE UPPER('%TEST1%')
  OR UPPER(TEXT) LIKE UPPER('%TEST2%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing UPPER(TEXT) on the last line.  Should be:

```
SELECT name, line, text 
FROM   user_source
WHERE  type = 'PROCEDURE' 
AND UPPER(text) LIKE UPPER('%test1%')
AND UPPER(TEXT) LIKE UPPER('%test2%')
```